# Python 3 sys.exc_info() call returns nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm raising an exception in python console:

```
1/0
```

I see this output on device:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

And I can get exception objects with:

```
import sys
sys.last_type, sys.last_value, sys.last_traceback
```

which returns:

```
(<class 'ZeroDivisionError'>, ZeroDivisionError('division by zero',), <traceback object at 0x0000022FB03BA608>)
```

However, the call to `sys.exc_info()` returns `(None, None, None)`.

Why is that?

My Python version is `Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

Answer (score 8):

`exc_info` returns the value of the **current** exception (see the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info)); by the time you're looking at it at the REPL, the exception isn't current anymore.

Here's an example usage that will work:

```
import sys
try:
    1 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print(sys.exc_info())
```

The important thing to remember is that **`exc_info()` needs to be called from within an except block.**

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to get non-current exceptions?

Comment: Got it. Is there something like `last_exc_info()`. Or is `sys.last_type, sys.last_value, sys.last_traceback` the only option?

Comment: As far as I know, that's the only option.  Sorry I can't help there!

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this issue when I wanted to include a traceback in a custom logging handler in a Flask project where an exception would be logged from a global @app.errorhandler annotated function.
Adding `exc_info=True` allowed me in that case to get exc_info also outside of an except block.

```py
logger.error("Some error occured", exc_info=True)
```